# String to Text - Line Break instead of comma

Tags: java

I need help before I'm totally despaired :D

As you will see I tried it in different ways even if there are just a really few differences. My problem is that I have a string which I want (or have) to output. This means I need it in a text file. Not that big problem, eh? But the actual problem is that I want line breaks instead of commas. I know I could just replace them after the file is written but it's just unnecessary when there is another way.

The Output looks like this

> [/rechtschreibung/_n, /rechtschreibung/_nauf, /rechtschreibung/_naus,
>   /rechtschreibung/_Ndrangheta, ....]

I want it to look like this

```
/rechtschreibung/_n
/rechtschreibung/_nauf
/rechtschreibung/_naus
/rechtschreibung/_Ndrangheta
```

Anyway even when I don't need this method later because I will store this and some other information into a database like sql. It will help me to build up the program step by step and learn some more Java ;)

So here is my code snippet

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;

//PrintWriter out
//= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));


try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bfwr.txt"));
    bw.write(test5.getWoerterListe().toString());
    bw.newLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

/*
try {
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("prwr.txt"));  
out.print(test5.getWoerterListe());  
out.close();  
System.out.printf("Testing String");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
*/

/*
try {
    FileWriter test10 = new FileWriter("test.txt");
    test10.write(test5.getWoerterListe().toString());
    test10.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
*/
```

Please be nice to me :D
Assistance appreciated =)

**EDIT #1**
Code directly before first one.

```
Oberordner test2 = new Oberordner("http://www.duden.de/definition");
Unterordner test3 = new Unterordner(test2.getOberOrdner());
WoerterListe test5 = new WoerterListe(test3.getUnterOrdnerURL());
test5.setWoerterListe();
```

and from WoerterListe.java the really end part

```
public ArrayList<String> getWoerterListe(){
    return WoerterListe;
}
```

Additional Information: the string is not stored in the code because there are tenthousands of words like `'/rechtschreibung/*'`
By the way the language here is german unfortunately I have to use german words =(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java developer and you didn't state what `getWoerterListe()` returns, but here's my guess.
`getWoerterListe()` probably return a list of strings, and the default behaviour of `toString()` in this case is to convert the list to comma seperated values. So instead of calling `toString()` on the list, loop through it and write out each line followed by a carriage return (or whatever Java uses to end lines).

Answer (score 0):

**Code**:

```
   String s = "[/rechtschreibung/_n, /rechtschreibung/_nauf, "
           + "/rechtschreibung/_naus, /rechtschreibung/_Ndrangheta, ....]";

   String srp = s.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\.+" ,"");
   String[] sp = srp.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(sp[i].trim());
    }
```

**Output**:

```
/rechtschreibung/_n
/rechtschreibung/_nauf
/rechtschreibung/_naus
/rechtschreibung/_Ndrangheta
```

**Explanation**:

I assumed `[/rechtschreibung/_n, /rechtschreibung/_nauf, /rechtschreibung/_naus, /rechtschreibung/_Ndrangheta, ....]` is a `String`. I removed all uncessary character like `[` , `]` , and any number of `.` form it. After that, I splited by , and print each element of splited string on the output.

Comment: i should have mentioned that there is another 'precode' connected to this. and the "string" is not written in the code. it's extracted out of html source code.

Comment: cannnot you convert it to String?

Comment: you did not answer me whether you can convert it to the String type?